# Tools -> Firebase->Storage connection Gradle sync failed after

Tags: android

Gradle sync failed: Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0 because no repositories are defined 
that's what happened to me after tools -> firebase -> storage connect

Answer (score 0):

Change external dependency `com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0`

to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'`

Also, did you add

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
```